# Database tables for defining sets

Tags: database

We have a table that contains a large amount (active records ~ 10,000,000) of transactions that we need to group together into large sets. Each transaction can be included in more than one set (i.e. marked) to denote that these transaction have been included in a specific export / batch. That seems to lend itself to a table of the following very simple structure:

id_transaction id_set

My question is, is this an established "pattern"? Is there a name for this type of table? Is it a good idea and are there other ways of doing this? For some reason my gut feeling says it may cause problems but is certainly better than saving big lists of ids in some other flat format. Next step is to do some prototyping but I hope somebody has some early insights.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your solution is correct.

A set is a thing where every (other) thing is either in or out. If a thing is in, designate the thing and the set. Query the set to get its things, query the thing to get those sets it is in. Wrap more complex functionality in transactions. Sounds good to me. The only thing I might add is that if you want your set to have some meta info (name, date, locale, etc) then you'll need that table as well, keyed on id_set.

Comment: Sorry forgot this one!